# How to bring back my database to wamp sever?

Tags: php, mysql, database, import, wamp

My server got crashed today morning, so before re-installing it I just copied the folder where my localhost was running so that my databases are not lost and trust me I preserved it safely. Now its re-installed and now my localhost is working but all I want is 'employee' database back to its place. How do I get it?

I copied the folder employee and saved back to where it was but its of no use. Am still stuck.

Reminding you, I didn't export it before re-installing. So can someone tell me how to face this situation?

Comment: These instructions are for *nix but should also work for Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2196350/44853

Comment: checkout this thread in  http://superuser.com/questions/616896/restoring-database-from-uninstalled-wamp-server

Comment: @SojanVJose : no use of it

Comment: Exactly which folder did you backup? What version of WAMPServer are you running? Is the database you are trying to recover a `MYISAM` or `INNODB` database? Did you re-install the same version of WAMPServer that was installed when it crashed?

Comment: i backed up entire wamp folder. and my wamp server 2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so assuming you did do a complete backup of the old wampserver folders you can try this.

First make sure you stop all service via wampmanager

```
wampmanager -> Stop all Services
```

Now make a backup of this folder on the newly installed WAMPServer, so you can return to a vanilla, just installed state if this does not work.

```
move \wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data \wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data_vanilla
```

Now copy your backed up MySQL folder from the Previous installations files to the new install

```
copy \old_wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data \wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data
```

Now lets clear the mysql log file, so you dont get confused between old and new message in the log.

```
move \wamp\logs\mysql.log \wamp\logs\old.mysql.log
```

You should now be able to restart the MYSQL service and see if it starts up cleanly.

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Start/Resume Service
```

Now if the wampmanager icon goes Orange, MySQL should have started. Check the mysql error log, to see if all is well.

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> MySQL log
```

If all is well, you can now start Apache as well.

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Start/Resume Service
```

The wampmanager icon should go green.

Answer (score 0):

when planning to recover, you should save the entire data directory . not just the folder with the database name .

---

refer the [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/616896/restoring-database-from-uninstalled-wamp-server) on superuser.

1. go to data directory of mysql (C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data )
2. Find a file called "mysql-bin.index"
3. Rename that file to "mysql-bin.index-corrupt"
4. Restart the server and it will work fine, all your database will be where you left them.

---

or this thread on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100621/restoring-mysql-databases-when-reinstalling-wamp) .

> INNODB databases will have been stored in the
>   \wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\ibdata1 file.
>
> There will also be info in a
>   \wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\DATA_BASE_NAME\ folder, one .frm file
>   for each table that was in the database, but this is basically just
>   schema information and not actual data.

If you do not have that file from the old install then your data is lost. check this [super user thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16875/mysql-how-to-restore-table-stored-in-a-frm-and-a-ibd-file) for further details .

Comment: i didn't find any file with that name. And to make you clear am using mysql5.6.17

Comment: @ManiKandan did you check the error log?  . check this thread too http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16875/mysql-how-to-restore-table-stored-in-a-frm-and-a-ibd-file  .

Comment: i have that.. I copied entire folder but even then its of no use

Comment: #1416 - la table "tablename"  ' n ' existe pas

Answer (score 0):

You need to import it back using phpmyadmin.

1. open localhost/phpmyadmin
2. select database then click import
3. locate the database and click go

You probably can find the data that you back up earlier in here, \wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlXX\data

Comment: I can't find any database in localhost